# not more than 2 images are stored in firebase using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, file-upload, google-cloud-firestore

I have used a multi-image picker and when the user selected the image I am storing the image path in the firebase. 1 or 2 paths are stored normally but when I send a path of more than 2 images it showed an exception and doesn't save the image.

below is the code of the multi-image picker which is working -:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fun1/Components/Rounded_Button.dart';
import 'package:fun1/Register_Options_Screens/RecoveryEmail.dart';
import 'package:fun1/Components/FabButton.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_absolute_path/flutter_absolute_path.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';




class PhotoSelectPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PhotoSelectPageState createState() => _PhotoSelectPageState();
}

class _PhotoSelectPageState extends State<PhotoSelectPage> {

  String selectedvalue;
  bool _isvisible = false;
  String _path;

  //==========================================================================image picker and store

  List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
  List files = [];
  List resultList = [];

  var data;
  // List<Asset> resultList;
  String _error = 'No Error Dectected';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  //============================================================to show image in a grid view
  Widget buildGridView() {
    if (images != null) {
      return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
          Asset asset = images[index];
          print(asset.getByteData(quality: 100));
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
              child: AssetThumb(
                asset: asset,
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      );
    }
    else{
      return Container();
    }
  }




  //============================================================to load multiple image from assets
  Future<void> loadAssets() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    String error = 'No Error Dectected';

    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 6,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
          actionBarTitle: "Choose Image",
          allViewTitle: "All Photos",
          useDetailsView: false,
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
        ),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      error = e.toString();
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
      _error = error;
    });
  }


  //===============================================================convert image to file and get the path
  getImagePathFromAsset(String path) async{
    final file = File(path);
    return file;
  }


  //=============================================================get and send the file to the backend

  _submit() async {
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      var path2 =
      await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(images[i].identifier);
      var file = await getImagePathFromAsset(path2);
      var base64Image = base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());
      files.add(base64Image);
      data = {
      'files': files,
    };


      print(data);

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => RecovermailScreen()));

      FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

      var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      firestore.collection('pal').doc('111445').set(
          {
            'name' : data,
          }).then((_){
        print("success!");
      });

      // print(firebaseUser);

    }
  }



  //====================================================================================global key declaration
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange[400],
      body: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 15),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                  

                Container(
                  height: 90,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 1,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Column(
                        children: [

                          buildList('Camera Roll'),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),


                images.isEmpty ? Container(height: 0,) :
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/5,
                    child: buildGridView(),
                  ),


                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                  

                      images.isEmpty ? Container() :
                      FabButton(
                        icon: Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
                        Iconcolor: Colors.deepOrange,
                        onpresses: () async{
                            _submit();
                         
                        },
                      ),


                    ],
                  ),
                ),


              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

and below is the error that I am getting when I send more than 2 file paths in the database.

```
Flutter run key commands.
h Repeat this help message.
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
I/flutter (22073): Instance of 'Future<ByteData>'
I/flutter (22073): Instance of 'Future<ByteData>'
I/flutter (22073): {files: [/9j/4VYLRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAARAA4BAgAgAAAA2gAAAA8BAgAgAAAA+gAAABABAgAgAAAAGgEAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBBQABAAAAOgEAABsBBQABAAAAQgEAACgB
AwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAgAAAASgEAADIBAgAUAAAAagEAABMCAwABAAAAAgAAACACBAABAAAAAAAAACECBAABAAAAAAAAACICBAABAAAAAAAAACMCBAABAAAAAAAAACQCBAABAAAAAQAAACUCAgAgAAAAfgEA
AGmHBAABAAAAngEAAFAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEhUQwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASFRDIERlc2lyZSA3MjggZHVhbCBzaW0AAAAAAAAAAABIAAAA
AQAAAEgAAAABAAAATWVkaWFUZWsgQ2FtZXJhIEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uCgAAAAAyMDE4OjExOjA3IDIwOjQ3OjQwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHQCaggUAAQAAAAADAACdggUAAQAA
AAgDAAAiiAMAAQAAAAAAAAAniAMAAQAAAPQBAAAAkAcABAAAADAyMjADkAIAFAAAABADAAAEkAIAFAAAACQDAAABkQcABAAAAAECAwAEkgoAAQAAADgDAAAHkgMAAQAAAAIAAAAIkgMAAQAAAP8AAAAJkgMA
AQAAAAAAAAAKkgUAAQAAAEADAAB8kgcAAAIAAEgDAACQkgIAAgAAADUzAACRkgIAAgAAADUzAACSkgIAAgAAADUzAAAAoAcABAAAADAxMDABoAMAAQAAAAEAAAACoAQAAQAAAAAKAAADoAQAAQAAAKAFAAAF
oAQAAQAAAMYFAAACpAMAAQAAAAAAAAADpAMAAQAAAAAAAAAEpAUAAQAAAEgFAAAGpAMAAQAAAAAAAAAIpAMAAQAAAAAAAAAJpAMAAQAAAA
I/flutter (22073): {files: [/9j/4VYLRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAARAA4BAgAgAAAA2gAAAA8BAgAgAAAA+gAAABABAgAgAAAAGgEAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBBQABAAAAOgEAABsBBQABAAAAQgEAACgB
AwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAgAAAASgEAADIBAgAUAAAAagEAABMCAwABAAAAAgAAACACBAABAAAAAAAAACECBAABAAAAAAAAACICBAABAAAAAAAAACMCBAABAAAAAAAAACQCBAABAAAAAQAAACUCAgAgAAAAfgEA
AGmHBAABAAAAngEAAFAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEhUQwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASFRDIERlc2lyZSA3MjggZHVhbCBzaW0AAAAAAAAAAABIAAAA
AQAAAEgAAAABAAAATWVkaWFUZWsgQ2FtZXJhIEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uCgAAAAAyMDE4OjExOjA3IDIwOjQ3OjQwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHQCaggUAAQAAAAADAACdggUAAQAA
AAgDAAAiiAMAAQAAAAAAAAAniAMAAQAAAPQBAAAAkAcABAAAADAyMjADkAIAFAAAABADAAAEkAIAFAAAACQDAAABkQcABAAAAAECAwAEkgoAAQAAADgDAAAHkgMAAQAAAAIAAAAIkgMAAQAAAP8AAAAJkgMA
AQAAAAAAAAAKkgUAAQAAAEADAAB8kgcAAAIAAEgDAACQkgIAAgAAADUzAACRkgIAAgAAADUzAACSkgIAAgAAADUzAAAAoAcABAAAADAxMDABoAMAAQAAAAEAAAACoAQAAQAAAAAKAAADoAQAAQAAAKAFAAAF
oAQAAQAAAMYFAAACpAMAAQAAAAAAAAADpAMAAQAAAAAAAAAEpAUAAQAAAEgFAAAGpAMAAQAAAAAAAAAIpAMAAQAAAAAAAAAJpAMAAQAAAA
I/flutter (22073): {files: [/9j/4VYLRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAARAA4BAgAgAAAA2gAAAA8BAgAgAAAA+gAAABABAgAgAAAAGgEAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBBQABAAAAOgEAABsBBQABAAAAQgEAACgB
AwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAgAAAASgEAADIBAgAUAAAAagEAABMCAwABAAAAAgAAACACBAABAAAAAAAAACECBAABAAAAAAAAACICBAABAAAAAAAAACMCBAABAAAAAAAAACQCBAABAAAAAQAAACUCAgAgAAAAfgEA
AGmHBAABAAAAngEAAFAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEhUQwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASFRDIERlc2lyZSA3MjggZHVhbCBzaW0AAAAAAAAAAABIAAAA
AQAAAEgAAAABAAAATWVkaWFUZWsgQ2FtZXJhIEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uCgAAAAAyMDE4OjExOjA3IDIwOjQ3OjQwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHQCaggUAAQAAAAADAACdggUAAQAA
AAgDAAAiiAMAAQAAAAAAAAAniAMAAQAAAPQBAAAAkAcABAAAADAyMjADkAIAFAAAABADAAAEkAIAFAAAACQDAAABkQcABAAAAAECAwAEkgoAAQAAADgDAAAHkgMAAQAAAAIAAAAIkgMAAQAAAP8AAAAJkgMA
AQAAAAAAAAAKkgUAAQAAAEADAAB8kgcAAAIAAEgDAACQkgIAAgAAADUzAACRkgIAAgAAADUzAACSkgIAAgAAADUzAAAAoAcABAAAADAxMDABoAMAAQAAAAEAAAACoAQAAQAAAAAKAAADoAQAAQAAAKAFAAAF
oAQAAQAAAMYFAAACpAMAAQAAAAAAAAADpAMAAQAAAAAAAAAEpAUAAQAAAEgFAAAGpAMAAQAAAAAAAAAIpAMAAQAAAAAAAAAJpAMAAQAAAA
E/flutter (22073): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/invalid-argument] Client specified an invalid argument
. Note that this differs from failed-precondition. invalid-argument indicates arguments that are problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g., an
 invalid field name).
E/flutter (22073): #0      MethodChannelDocumentReference.set (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_referen
ce.dart:43)
E/flutter (22073): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22073): #1      _PhotoSelectPageState._submit.<anonymous closure> (package:hitch_fun1/Register_Options_Screens/PhotoSelect_Screen.dart:151)
E/flutter (22073): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22073):
E/flutter (22073): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/invalid-argument] Client specified an invalid argument
. Note that this differs from failed-precondition. invalid-argument indicates arguments that are problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g., an
 invalid field name).
E/flutter (22073): #0      MethodChannelDocumentReference.set (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_referen
ce.dart:43)
E/flutter (22073): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22073): #1      _PhotoSelectPageState._submit.<anonymous closure> (package:hitch_fun1/Register_Options_Screens/PhotoSelect_Screen.dart:151)
E/flutter (22073): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22073):
E/flutter (22073): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/invalid-argument] Client specified an invalid argument
. Note that this differs from failed-precondition. invalid-argument indicates arguments that are problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g., an
 invalid field name).
E/flutter (22073): #0      MethodChannelDocumentReference.set (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_referen
ce.dart:43)
E/flutter (22073): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22073): #1      _PhotoSelectPageState._submit.<anonymous closure> (package:hitch_fun1/Register_Options_Screens/PhotoSelect_Screen.dart:151)
E/flutter (22073): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22073):
```

can anyone guide me to the problem as i am stuck here.
thank you.

Comment: if you log the array that have the images string paths, what do you see?

Comment: path of the image

Comment: Ok, it's just a hypothesis but I guess you are trying to upload byte type data to firestore and not strings. this is what that line of `base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());`. When you upload 1-2 files, it works but when you upload more, it doesn't work and that's makes me sure that you are hitting the limit of [firestore document which is only 1MB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields). the recommended approach is to upload your files to Firebase Storage and add a url reference for them to firestore.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you use Firebase Cloud storage for storing your files and get the file download url

After getting the file download url from firebase cloud storage you can then save all the url in an array which you can save into firebase firestore as a string or list

Comment: i am still not able to use Firebase Cloud storage as soon as I use that dependencies it throws above exception

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase Cloud storage for storing images then get the URL
to store in the Firebase

there's an example you can to get the idea

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;

class AddImage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddImageState createState() => _AddImageState();
}

class _AddImageState extends State<AddImage> {
  bool uploading = false;
  double val = 0;
  CollectionReference imgRef;
  firebase_storage.Reference ref;

  List<File> _image = [];
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Add Image'),
          actions: [
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    uploading = true;
                  });
                  uploadFile().whenComplete(() => Navigator.of(context).pop());
                },
                child: Text(
                  'upload',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ))
          ],
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
              child: GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: _image.length + 1,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return index == 0
                        ? Center(
                            child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                                onPressed: () =>
                                    !uploading ? chooseImage() : null),
                          )
                        : Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: FileImage(_image[index - 1]),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                          );
                  }),
            ),
            uploading
                ? Center(
                    child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'uploading...',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      CircularProgressIndicator(
                        value: val,
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
                      )
                    ],
                  ))
                : Container(),
          ],
        ));
  }

  chooseImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image.add(File(pickedFile?.path));
    });
    if (pickedFile.path == null) retrieveLostData();
  }

  Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
    final LostData response = await picker.getLostData();
    if (response.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    if (response.file != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image.add(File(response.file.path));
      });
    } else {
      print(response.file);
    }
  }

  Future uploadFile() async {
    int i = 1;

    for (var img in _image) {
      setState(() {
        val = i / _image.length;
      });
      ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('images/${Path.basename(img.path)}');
      await ref.putFile(img).whenComplete(() async {
        await ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
          imgRef.add({'url': value});
          i++;
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    imgRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('imageURLs');
  }
}
```